# C++ iterator, do I need to reset after using set find method

Tags: c++, stl

Should I need to call reset method or anything, when I try to use c++ stl set find method multiple times?

Comment: Please post some code. If your code isn't working, please state what you expect and why the result isn't what you expect to see.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? Is there some particular problem you're having?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`set::find` is a `const` method, it doesn't change the container. It doesn't work in findfirst/findnext style. You can call it multiple times without any additional actions.

Comment: Nope. The find, lower_bound, upper_bound and equal_range member functions each have two versions, one const
and the other non-const. In each case the behavior of the two functions is identical except that the const version
returns a const_iterator and the non-const version an iterator. 23.3.1.3